# Skip empty rows in reading csv excel file in php

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have a code where a csv file is uploaded ,the data is extracted from it and uploaded to database.Everything works fine,but how can i skip the empty rows and continue reading the rows with data in it.

This is the code where i extract data from csv file

```
if (($source = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
//read data from excel
while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $question=$data[0];
    $point=$data[1];
    $header=$data[2];
    $footer=$data[3];
    $type_value=$data[4];
    $group_name=$data[5];
        echo $question;

}// while end

}
```

Comment: `if (empty($data[0])) { continue; }` something like this at the start of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP's [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) instead of the basic fgetcsv() function, it has built-in options to skip empty lines:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($csv_file);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);
foreach ($file as $data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats nice..Let me try that

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($data[0] == NULL)
         continue;
```

This is because fgetcsv returns a non-empty array with a null element inside.

Comment: With this, if the first elemnt is empty, it skips the line altogether. (e.g: [, 1, 2]). Better line would be: if (count($data)<=1 & !$data[0]) continue;

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
if ($data === null) continue;
```

I didn't test it, but I sthink it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (($source = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
// read data from excel
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        if ((string) $data[0] != '0' and empty($data[0]))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $question   = $data[0];
        $point      = $data[1];
        $header     = $data[2];
        $footer     = $data[3];
        $type_value = $data[4];
        $group_name = $data[5];

        echo $question;
    }
}
```

Comment: As there are many columns,a large set of conditions will be required right?

Comment: i minimized the condition.  the reason i put (string) $data[0] != '0' in condition because empty() function treats 0 as empty value also